# R Extract values from data frame with vectors

Tags: r, subset

I hope my question is not a duplicate, but I really couldn't find what I need. I dived in dplyr and even did the data.table course from DataCamp, but I can't fix it. Maybe overlooking something?

I have this df:

```
set.seed(1964)
df<-data.frame(id = c( "XEY", "NZH", "DYE", "JNF", "LHH", "WNB"),
           q_1 = sample(5,6, replace = TRUE),
           q_2 = sample(5,6, replace = TRUE),
           q_3 = sample(5,6, replace = TRUE),
           q_4 = sample(5,6, replace = TRUE),
           q_5 = sample(5,6, replace = TRUE))
```

So my df looks like this:

[image]

Next I have two vectors with id's (row-indicators) and q's (question numbers) like these:

```
id <- c("XEY", "DYE", "JNF", "DYE", "XEY", "LHH", "WNB", "JNF" )
question <- c("val_1", "val_1","val_3","val_3","val_3", "val_4", "val_4", "val_5")
```

I want to extract the values from the df using the two vectors to get an output like this:

[image]

I have tried a lot of things to extract the values, but I keep getting errors. I have tried things like:

```
df[id == (id[1]), (question[1])]
df[id == id[1], question[1]]
```

The strange thing is that the data.table package seems to accept the 'row-notation'. Because:

```
df[id == (id[1]),]
```

gives back the valuea for row "XEY":

```
    id q_1 q_2 q_3 q_4 q_5
1: XEY   5   1   5   4   1
```

But how to do the trick for the right column notation using my vector?

Sorry for this very basic question, appreciate your help.

Comment: can you also manually construct a data.frame which indicates your desired output?

Comment: Something like this? The way of commenting differs very much from the way I can share info in the question:  `id <- c("XEY", "DYE", "JNF", "DYE", "XEY", "LHH", "WNB", "JNF" )`  
    `question <- c("val_1", "val_1","val_3","val_3","val_3", "val_4", "val_4", "val_5")` 
`value <- c(5, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2, 2, 3)` 
`output <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, question, value))`

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with  tidyr.
I add stringsAsFactors=FALSE to your df to avoid a warning during the join.

```
set.seed(1964)
df<-data.frame(id = c( "XEY", "NZH", "DYE", "JNF", "LHH", "WNB"),
       q_1 = sample(5,6, replace = TRUE),
       q_2 = sample(5,6, replace = TRUE),
       q_3 = sample(5,6, replace = TRUE),
       q_4 = sample(5,6, replace = TRUE),
       q_5 = sample(5,6, replace = TRUE),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
id <- c("XEY", "DYE", "JNF", "DYE", "XEY", "LHH", "WNB", "JNF" )
question <- c("q_1", "q_1","q_3","q_3","q_3", "q_4", "q_4", "q_5")

library(tidyr)
df2 <- data.frame(id,question,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df %>% gather(k,Value,-id) %>% inner_join(df2,by="id") %>% filter(question==k) %>% arrange(question) %>%
    select(-k)
```

Comment: Wauw! THANKS! i am going to study on your answer to grasp what you are doing, but it worked!!!

Answer (score 3):

In base R you can do the following.

```
Value <- diag(as.matrix(df[match(id, df$id), sub("val", "q", question)]))
result <- data.frame(id, Question = sub("val", "q", question), Value)
result
#   id Question Value
#1 XEY      q_1     5
#2 DYE      q_1     1
#3 JNF      q_3     2
#4 DYE      q_3     1
#5 XEY      q_3     5
#6 LHH      q_4     2
#7 WNB      q_4     2
#8 JNF      q_5     3
```

**Edit.**

After seeing the answer by @Nicolas2, with the use of `inner_join`, I have decided to give `merge` a try. But to do it I will need function `melt` from external package `reshape2`.

```
df2 <- data.frame(id, question = sub("val", "q", question))
df3 <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "id")
names(df3)[2] <- "question"
result2 <- merge(df2, df3)
result2
#   id question value
#1 DYE      q_1     1
#2 DYE      q_3     1
#3 JNF      q_3     2
#4 JNF      q_5     3
#5 LHH      q_4     2
#6 WNB      q_4     2
#7 XEY      q_1     5
#8 XEY      q_3     5
```

The result is the same, with a different row order.

Comment: Hi Rui. You too thanks a lot. I am going to study your solutions, am learning a lot today!